# persistent accesibility settings

Tags: unity, mouse, system-settings, accessibility

I am trying to modify accessibility settings using unity tweak tool to make the mouse cursor larger. It works, however, as soon as I log out and log back in the mouse returns to it's normal size and a message is displayed about some sort of error. It seems that Ubuntu isn't able to persist the settings from one session to another. How can I fix this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm not too familiar with Unity tweak tools, as I do minor tweaks through the terminal mostly.

There is a way you can change the size of the cursor through the terminal, and it's automated:

```
dconf write /org/gnome/desktop/interface/cursor-size 48
```

You can change the 48 to any number of your choice, and if the cursor still resets after reboots, then try creating a startup command that changes the size for you.

:)

Comment: for some reason this doesn't persist. i tried adding this to .profile but it produces an error...

Comment: That's odd. Do you remember what the error is? If not that's OK. Again there is always the option to make the code I stated above launch at login

Comment: the error was about dconf usage (dont' remember exactly) stating the appropriate way to use it. to do it at login, where would you put the command.. i thought it would be in .profile?

Comment: Oh sorry, I should've been more clear. To make the command run at startup, use the Dash to find and open Startup Applications. Click Add and enter dconf write /org/gnome/desktop/interface/cursor-size 48 into the command box. You can add an optional name or comment if you please, then when you are finished, press OK and reboot to test.

Comment: It would be great of you could add the instructions from your last comment to your response. Comments are not persistent (or not guaranteed to be).